# Monitoring Edge.js Tasks from C#

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

My goal is to be able to cancel a long running Node.js task that has been called from C# using Edge.js.

When using tasks normally, you can specify a cancellation token, give your task some time to execute, then cancel it if it is going beyond your time limit.

I can't figure out how to define/call the Edge.Func Node function/task and pass in a cancellation token to be able to kill the process if it goes too long.  Maybe I'm thinking about this from the wrong angle...

Any insight would be most helpful, thanks!